# Disk durability when using RAID 10 vs RAID 5

Tags: hard-drive, raid, raid-5, hardware-raid

Most of the time technical articles about different RAID levels mostly about
how redundant they are, how fast on read/write etc.

But I can't find information about would a disk in a certain RAID
live longer than on other RAID level. (ignoring the capacity, speed and redundancy factors)

Especially I am interested in RAID 5 vs RAID 10.

RAID 5 allows us redundancy when one disk fail
RAID 10 allows us at least 1 disk fail redundancy.

But if we have two 100% servers (except different raid levels)
wit the same data, the same load etc. (again, despite the capacity factor)

so, in which, RAID disks would "live" longer?

for RAID 5, a RAID controller would calculate parity on any write/read, correct?
this is penalty.

for RAID 10 it would mirror and stripe

It is all about Hardware RAID if it matters!

Comment: Simplifying the question. In which RAID (5 or 10) disks are busy more? if they are working in 100% identical environment (the same operations)

Comment: The consensus these days is that RAID 10 is superior in many regards to RAID 5 in terms of performance, reliability, and cost effectiveness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's almost no evidence that disk activity level has any effect on disk life at all. So it won't matter.

Comment: Really? Disk durability depends on what, then?

Comment: Luck, temperature, and how many hours a day the disk is spinning. (See the [Google study](http://storagemojo.com/2007/02/19/googles-disk-failure-experience/), among other sources.)